# How to listen to a JFace Viewer node changes?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

How can I listen to a JFace Viewer when when a node has been added, removed or modified?

I'm not sure if the best way is to create my own event handler and override the refresh method to fire that event.

Comment: The viewer is just showing you a model as filtered through the content provider. Can you listen to the *model*?

Comment: @nitind I do can listen to the model but I only want to specifically listen when the user added a new node through the Viewer itself. So maybe I should create my own fireEvent for that specific action.